# R Shiny: Creating New Columns Within a Reactive Data Frame

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, cbind

Say I have a data frame called `summarized` which includes the columns `TY_COMP` and `LY_COMP` (among others). I could write a function in R that performs a calculation on `TY_COMP` and `LY_COMP` and creates a new column called `cac` in the data frame like this:

```
summarized$cac <- summarized$TY_COMP/summarized$LY_COMP-1
```

`cac` is now a new column in the summarized data frame.

Now say that `summarized()` is a reactive data frame with the same columns.

How could I achieve the effect done in the non-reactive data frame, i.e. create a new column within the current frame? Or how would I get the same effect?

I tried:

```
summarized$cac <- reactive({summarized()$TY_COMP/summarized()$LY_COMP-1})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you want to modify a `reactive` when for example an `actionButton` is clicked. For this purpose I would use `reactiveValues`. You can modify `reactiveValue` inside of observers such as `observe` or `observeEvent`.

Check out this simple example:

```
summarized <- data.frame(id = 1:20, group = letters[1:4], TY_COMP = runif(20), LY_COMP = runif(20))

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("text"),
  actionButton("btn", "Add the 'cac' column to summarized")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  rv <- reactiveValues(summarized = summarized)

  output$text <- renderPrint(rv$summarized)

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    rv$summarized$cac <- summarized$TY_COMP / summarized$LY_COMP - 1
  })

  summarized_mod <- reactive({
    summarized()$TY_COMP / summarized()$LY_COMP-1
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Another option would be to create another `reactive` that has an additional column. This is possible to use, but depending on your use case, I recommend the first solution.

Example:

```
summarized <- data.frame(id = 1:20, group = letters[1:4], TY_COMP = runif(20), LY_COMP = runif(20))

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text2")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$text1 <- renderPrint(summarized_orig())
  output$text2 <- renderPrint(summarized_mod())


  summarized_orig <- reactive( {
    summarized
  })

  summarized_mod <- reactive({
    df <- summarized_orig()
    df$cac <- summarized_orig()$TY_COMP / summarized_orig()$LY_COMP - 1

    df
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In the first example, why is this being done twice - summarized$TY_COMP / summarized$LY_COMP, once as reactive and other without ()

Comment: I figured that was just a modified version, however I am unable to use the modified version. I have raised a query related to this in a separate thread

Comment: Was confronted with a similar problem and your answer solved my issue with some tweaks. Super helpful !