# Reactive values - what am I doing wrong

Tags: shiny, reactive-programming

The app is intended to display summarized_mod when the action button is clicked. But I keep getting a  summarized_mod missing error.

```
summarized <- data.frame(id = 1:20, group = letters[1:4], TY_COMP = runif(20), LY_COMP = runif(20))

    library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      verbatimTextOutput("text"),
      actionButton("btn", "Show the summarized")
    )

    server <- function(input, output){
              summarized <- reactive({summarized})
                observeEvent(input$btn,{ 
        summarized_mod <-summarized()$TY_COMP / summarized()$LY_COMP-1 } 
               })

      output$text <- renderPrint(summarized_mod())
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Firstly, you use the same name (`summarized`) for two different things, that's weird.

Comment: Picked up the example from this thread :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799252/r-shiny-creating-new-columns-within-a-reactive-data-frame

Comment: Ok, but don't do that... Secondly, `summarized_mod` is a vector locally defined in the observer. This is not a function nor a reactive conductor. So `summarized_mod()` in the `renderPrint` is doubly wrong: 1) `summarized_mod` does not exist here, and 2) even if it did, the parentheses `()` make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:20, 
                  group = letters[1:4], 
                  TY_COMP = runif(20), 
                  LY_COMP = runif(20))

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("text"),
  actionButton("btn", "Show the summarized")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  # summarized <- reactive({summarized}) useless !
  summarized_mod <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
    dat$TY_COMP / dat$LY_COMP-1
  })
  output$text <- renderPrint(summarized_mod())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```